# What is the best practice for overriding strings in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

I often have the situation where the wording of specific strings from various modules or core features needs to be changed for specific tenants & themes in Orchard CMS.

For example, I may have a client that prefers to have the shopping cart checkout button say "Checkout Now" rather than "Go to checkout" which is a string contained within a view in a shopping module.

I can simply override the razor view in my theme and change the string, however views often are quite complex, and it doesn't feel right overriding a view just to change one string.

Another approach I have tried is to define a po translation file within my theme to override the string from the module. This works because the strings in the module are defined using the T() syntax. However, I've noticed that as soon as I define an override for a string within my theme, this override effects all tenants, instead of just the one tenant that has this theme enabled. I'm inclined to think that translations within modules/themes should be ignored from tenants where they are not enabled.

So I'm left wondering what the best approach for this scenario is?

The localisation/po file approach would be ok if tenants ignored po files from themes that aren't enabled, but then again, it would be really nice if there was a module or feature in core that allowed you to specify string overrides via the admin interface. I guess it's more of a "rewording" task than a "translation" task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way of doing this is through template overrides. If you don't want to do that, you can actually break shapes down, and delegate the rendering to smaller templates that are easier to override. This is done by simply refactoring the part of a template that you want to be able to override individually into a separate template. This post explains how to do that: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/creating-shapes-on-the-fly

If you're not willing to do that, you can use this module to get strings from the database instead of po files: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Q42.DbTranslations It should be possible to modify it to fit your sceanrio.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I wasn't aware of that module. At a glance it looks like it may suit my purposes. I really just want an easy way for my tenants to reword strings without having to make code/theme modifications.